# Generate unique registration code based on name and last name

Tags: c#, registration

I am collecting first name and last name from a user in a registration process. I want to generate a unique registration  code using first name and last name without checking in the database for all the existing codes. John Cano can generate something like `JC76AS1` where `JC` if from John Cano .

What could be the best way to generate the code part `76AS1` without check the database for existing code and trying to don't create a duplicated a registration code?

Comment: Personally I'd use a GUID (or append a GUID, if you really need the JC part). If you can't check for collisions, that's one of the most secure way to get an unique identifier IMO. And _no_, do not try to truncate a GUID to shorten the code length.

Comment: If you can keep a counter then it's easy. JC00001, JS00002.

Comment: yes but a counter can be a very easy pattern to break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it would be possible to do that without checking it in the database or maintaining a reference of already generated registration codes in memory.

You can use GUID and append that to FirstName's first character and last name's first character. But it will be long, but **unique**.

```
string firstName = "John";
string lastName = "Cano";
string uniqueRegistrationCode = string.Format("{0}{1}-{2}", firstName[0], lastName[0], Guid.NewGuid());
```

and you would get back something like:

`JC-3f507a3c-cd80-482d-b3be-c8002856926e`

*(this assuming that there is at least one character in first and last name)*